# How long would it take to index 30-40 GB of data in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search-indexing

How long would it take to index of my 7 `.pst` files that total 30-40 GB data. The indexing has been running for the two days and has not stopped yet..

My PC an Intel i3, 8GB RAM, SSD.

I set up index properties and content of `.pst` and `.ost` files.

Answer (score 1):

The specific time is determined by many aspects. You can click "Search tab > Search Tools > Index Status" to see how many items are remained to be indexed.

If the number to be indexed is decreasing, the Outlook client is still under searching. You may need to wait for some more time.

If the number doesn’t change, Outlook searching is stuck. You can rebuild the index to test the result. To do this, exit Outlook and go to "Control Panel > Indexing Options > Advanced." Under "Index Settings" tab, click Rebuild.

Besides, if the PST files are corrupted, the indexing will also take a long time or get stuck. You can also follow the steps in [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repair-outlook-data-files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253) to repair PST files.